# Firebase's Angularfire not firing catch on $signInWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: firebase, angularfire

When calling any of the AngularFire samples,I'm getting responses from the server, but methods in then & catch are not firing

```
 Html:
script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js">/script>
script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js">/script>
script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.0.0/angularfire.min.js"> 

Javscript:
// Factory from example
    myApp.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
      function($firebaseAuth) {
        return $firebaseAuth();
      }
    ]);

    // Function called from inside controller
            Auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword("my@email.com", "password").then(function(firebaseUser) {
      console.log("Signed in as:", firebaseUser.uid);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
    });
```

I'm unable to get the then or catch logic to fire.  Instead the output is:

> firebase.js:75 Uncaught Error: There is no user record corresponding
>   to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.

Should the .catch portion be where this is caught.  I had this working in the old firebase, but I recall it not always being reliable there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was a bug in AngularFire 2.0.0 lib. Try to import 2.0.1.

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.0.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm using 2.0.1 and still don't get errors in the catch() block of $signInWithEmailAndPassword

Comment: Check if you're calling it the same way (scope.login function, line 21): https://github.com/igorrendulic/smokeless/blob/master/www/js/controller.js

Comment: I got a reply from the firebase developers, the error was not being sent to the catch block because the arguments themselves were wrong (missing in my test case), so the error was handled synchronously to avoid the Promise error black hole phenomenon. It seems to be as designed in that case.